# Proof of variance of $S_n^2$

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, statistical-inference

Let

$$
   S_n^2= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \overline{X}
$$

I'm looking for a clear simple proof of the variance of this just for personal knowledge to derive the $MSE$ later on any input would be appreciated.

Comment: @qwr Do not alter the meaning of the post without notifying the author. Also, your edit still did not reflect the usual definition of variance.

Comment: You probably mean
$$S_n^2 = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline X)^2$$
If this is correct, please adapt.

Comment: @AlexR There is no formula for variance without the parentheses.

Comment: @qwr The variance still squares those differences; your edit did not reflect that. And if the OP is unable to pose a correct question, it's his problem I'd say

Comment: @qwr $$\sigma^2 = E((X-E(X))^2) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$$
Actually needs no such parentheses btw ;)
$$\sigma^2 = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \frac1{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \cdot \sum_{j=1}^n X_j $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am assuming you know that the MSE is the (biased) sample variance: $MSE=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (estimate_i-actual_i)^2$ when you replace your "actual" by the sample mean and the "estiamte" by your sample data. Also, your notation is a little ambiguous, as its not clear if the sample average is inside or outside of the summation. Numerically, it doesn't matter, so I will address both:

1) If  $\overline{X}$ is *outside* of the summation, then note that $\frac{1}{n} \sum X_i = \overline{X}$. Therefore, your formula **always** evaluates to zero, so it has $0$ variance.

2) If $\overline{X}$ is *inside* the summation, then you get $\frac{1}{n} \sum X_i -\frac{1}{n} n\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum X_i -\overline{X}$, which is just case (1) above, so again you get zero.

The answer to your question is that the expression has zero variance.

Comment: i eventually arrived at this answer but thank you for your solution!